# Which one is better from get_template_directory_uri VS get_theme_file_uri and why?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I'm coding for WordPress theme basically for `wp_enqueue_scripts()` then I noticed a thing. I saw the `get_theme_file_uri()` working fine also the `get_template_directory_uri()` working fine

```
wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-css', get_theme_file_uri("/assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"), null, "1.0");
```

---

And

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css', null, '1.0' );
```

So I'm really confused which one will use in my code and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function definition of get_theme_file_uri() should tell you correct answer.

```
function get_theme_file_uri( $file = '' ) {
    $file = ltrim( $file, '/' );

    if ( empty( $file ) ) {
        $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    } elseif ( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file ) ) {
        $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;
    } else {
        $url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'theme_file_uri', $url, $file );
}
```

As you can see it checks child theme first and checks if the file exist or not.
If you are not using child theme and you are sure the file exists then you can use get_template_directory_uri() for better performance.